# What is the best method to retrieve the post value on another page in ASP.net 4.0

Tags: c#, asp.net

I search on internet but did not find any best solution, i found one way, where you need to code html tags like

```
<input type='text'> ... etc etc
```

and retrieve that value on another page as

```
Request.Form["name of input text field"];
```

[W3Schools -ASP Forms and User Input](http://www.w3schools.com/asp/asp_inputforms.asp)

exists any better way to retrieve that post value??

Comment: Clarify what "best" means to you. Performance? Typing? Succinctness? Robust?

Comment: I think you mean get the post value of the request made (surely to a different page as the initial one). If so, yes, that's the way. What is the problem you are facing with it? It's really simple.

Comment: took me a while to know what u asking, but yeh query string is what I used :)

Comment: RefFilter: best means which step adopts by a good programmers...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASP.NET WebForms has support for cross-page posting. Read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178139.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178140.aspx for more information.

**Example:**

**WebForm1.aspx:**
Note the asp:button has its PostBackUrl property set.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebFormApplication.WebForm1" EnableViewStateMac="false" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server" >
    <div>

        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" PostBackUrl="WebForm2.aspx" />

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**WebForm2.aspx:**
Note that I've added the PreviousPageType directive here.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm2.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebFormApplication.WebForm2" %>
<%@ PreviousPageType VirtualPath="WebForm1.aspx" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        This is page 2
        <asp:Label Text="n/a" runat="server" ID="Label1" ></asp:Label>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**WebForm2.aspx.cs:** (Codebehind)

```
public partial class WebForm2 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(PreviousPage.IsCrossPagePostBack)
        {
            var tb = PreviousPage.FindControl("TextBox1") as TextBox;
            Label1.Text = tb.Text;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why using PreviousPage when you can simply use Request.Form["TextBox1"], accessing PreviousPage will execute whole Page lifecycle for previous page

Comment: @AntonioBakula: AFAIK you will not run the previous page's lifecycle with PreviousPage.

Answer (score 0):

The example you provide is useful for asp pages but I recommend to use [QueryString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.querystring.aspx) collection for passing parameters between webforms in asp.net

Here is an example of how to use it :

```
using System;
using System.Web.UI;

public partial class _Default : Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    string v = Request.QueryString["Param1"];
    if (v != null)
    {
        Response.Write("param is ");
        Response.Write(v);
    }
    }
}
```

You could use Response.Redirect for concatenate the URL :

```
string _url = string.Format("../WebFormA.aspx?Param1={0}&Param2={1}", _param1, _param2);
Response.Redirect(_url);
```

Regards.

Comment: i don't see any real advantage from using QueryString(GET) over Form(POST)