# How to pass parameters from one page to another?

Tags: c#, asp.net, events

I have the following code behind:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
      List<GlassesCollection> gc= BL.Example.GetCategory() ;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        rpt1.DataSource = gc;
        rpt1.DataBind();
    }

    protected void rpt1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {

     Button btn = (Button)e.Item.FindControl("btn1");
     btn.CommandArgument = DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem,"CollectionID").ToString();
   }
}
```

I want to pass the content of the btn.CommandArgument to Label's event that placed in another ASPX.CS file.
Is there any way to implement this?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: well, there are lots of ways to pass parameters to other pages, sending via get method "?param=value&param2=value2" etc. or storing in session object, or application object, or even using static class/object to store passing parameters from a page to others. implementation is basically depends on the architecture of the application you work on.

Comment: If cross-page posting is an option, you could look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8747946/what-is-the-best-method-to-retrieve-the-post-value-on-another-page-in-asp-net-4/8748657#8748657

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [QueryStrings](http://www.dotnetperls.com/querystring). For example, your url will can look like:

```
string url = String.Format("http://www.example.com/somepage.aspx?labeltext={0}",btn.CommandArgument);
```

Then, in your `somepage.aspx`, you can have:

```
//"labeltext" is the same name we used above as the ID
string lblText = Request.QueryString["labeltext"];
if (lblText != null)
{ 
   myLabel.Text = lblText;
}
```

If there's a chance that the text might not be suitable for passing in a URL, you can encode it with [HttpServerUtility.UrlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zttxte6w.aspx) and then decode it with [HttpServerUtility.UrlDecode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6196h3wt.aspx) before assigning it to the label.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Session. Put value in Session and read it in another page.

```
Session["key"]=value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the query string for that:

```
Response.Redirect("AnotherPage.aspx?CommandArgument=SomeArgument");
```

Then read the QueryString on `AnotherPage.aspx`

```
string commArgument = Request.QueryString["CommandArgument"];
```